# Q: EtherCAT local as slave

Tags: twincat

For a school project we're attempting to establish a connection between TwinCAT & ROS, with TwinCAT as slave and ROS as the master.

I'd like to know if it's possible for TwinCAT run locally to behave as a slave in the TcXaeShell.
And if yes, I'd like to know how to set up TwinCAT as slave in a TcXaeShell.

All tutorials reagarding masters & slaves treat TwinCAT running in the shell as the master, making me doubt if its possible for TwinCAT being run as a slave locally.

With kind regards,

Schweini

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but for it to work the TwinCAT device/PLC needs to have an EtherCAT slave controller.
One way (depending on your hardware setup/requirements) is to order a PLC with the [B110 extension](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/b110_ethercat_optioninterface/1982202891.html&id=).
Another way is by utilizing an [EtherCAT bridge](https://www.beckhoff.com/en-en/products/i-o/ethercat-terminals/el6xxx-communication/el6695.html). This will act as a bridge between two masters. It works between it has two slaves built-in which exchange data between each other.

Answer (score 0):

TwinCAT can be run as a slave without the EtherCAT Slave Controller (ESC) hardware by using the TwinCAT Simulator: https://www.beckhoff.com/en-en/products/automation/twincat/te1xxx-twincat-3-engineering/te1111.html.

Another option for running on a standard PC without an ESC is the acontis EC-Simulator: https://www.acontis.com/en/ethercat-simulation.html